# Finding all the subdomains and registered email addresses?

Tags: email

Could you please explain, how to find all of the existed subdomains of a domain address and registered email addresses of these subdomains?

- I found a website called snov.io but it only shows some of the email addresses, also it doesn't work for subdomains.
- The second website called robtex.com, but this one is not for finding email addresses. It shows some of the subdomains but not all of them. Sometimes it requires to find subdomain of a subdomain of a domain.
- I'm talking of tens of thousands (50k) email addresses, maybe more. Probably I would need some automation. I'm not an ethical hacker or pentester, I have knowledge of the C language and very limited Python experience. If I need any other website, software, OS or programming language, please refer their names. It is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not possible.  There is no way to lookup either sub domains or email addresses.  You either find published ones, brute force guess, or gain access to the systems where DNS/email is hosted and directly look it up.  Note that the second option is probably illegal and the third option definitely is.  None of these options are very practical or effective.

Comment: With snov.io I've found 18k email address. Could you please explain me how does it that website found all of these emails? What is its way? What is the name of this procedure? How does "robtex.com" found some of the subdomain names? Maybe I can have a clue about what they are doing if I can get the names of these procedures? Because I really dont know. I really need to search more.

Comment: You would have to ask them.  However, again, it is not possible to just go get a list of emails or subdomains for a given domain.  snov.io has probably just spent years scraping every email address they can find.  To be clear, that would fall under "find published ones"

Comment: Dear Conor thanks for the information. I'm really surprised how did they manage to find all of the email addresses which are not publicly exposed on google.  Please exceuse my illiteracy/lack of knowlodge about this field

Comment: If the domain's DNS is misconfigured, you can get a zone transfer that includes all of its hosts, but that's really unlikely. Otherwise, you can use [Passive DNS](https://www.spamhaus.com/resource-center/what-is-passive-dns-a-beginners-guide/) to get a partial list of known subdomains. Anything that would reveal email addresses is a spam risk (and requires active polling that will alert security teams), so I don't suggest that route.

Answer (score 1):

So, let's suppose you have a domain, e.g. stackexchange.com

Only their subdomains would know all its subdomains. In fact, it is possible that it has a wildcard (like stackexchange.com), so *anything* ending exists. For example: https://subdomainforquestion241763bymkde.stackexchange.com There is not a website there ("Site not found"), but the subdomain exists.

If the nameserver was misconfigured, you would be able to get a copy of the zone from them (a zone transfer). It shouldn't let you do that, though.

With no knowledge of the real data, it is possible to find *some* of the subdomains, for example search engines will typically discover subdomains, which you can then show on their search results. DNS resolvers can log the queries that people do, and from searching on that history, get all the subdomains that people requested *through them*. This is probably what robtex does.

As for the registered email addresses of these subdomains, that's a concept which doesn't exist. A domain will be registered to someone, and their email would be listed on the whois entry for the domain (assuming the tld doesn't block it, it wasn't registered through a privacy whois service, and that it wasn't now removed after GDPR changes). However, the subdomains belong to the same entity as the registered domain. There won't be an email for someone that registered it (actually, the holder of the domain might have given the subdomain to someone else, like a university giving control of the "cs" subdomain to the computer science department, but it's up to the owner of the domain to relinquish / claim back that control, and to track in any way their wish to, who is making use of it).

Comment: Dear Angel, thanks for detailed explanation. I will check the technical terms you've mentioned and what do they mean and come back again if I don't understand or find something on google.